# What are all possible values of Alexa request's supportedInterfaces property

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, voice-recognition

Alexa [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html) describes the `supportedInterfaces` property on its request in the following manner:

[image]

Besides `AudioPlayer` mentioned there, where can one see a **full listing** of supported interfaces that can appear in a request?

Currently, when testing from Alexa Developer Console, the collection of supportedInterfaces is not populated.

[image]

Is that the normal behavior?  I would think that at least an AudioPlayer should have been populated, or not?  How can one make it populated?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#service-interface-reference-json)?

Answer (score 1):

Echo Show has the following keys:

```
"supportedInterfaces":{
    "Display":{},
    "AudioPlayer": {},             
    "VideoApp":{}
}
```

Source: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/12826e9e-e06a-4ab4-a583-8e074709a9f3/how-to-build-alexa-skills-for-echo-show1

I noticed when using the app, you also get this one:

```
"supportedInterfaces": {
    "Geolocation": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ASK-SDK](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) team maintains TypeScript definitions for their codebase. You can check what supported interfaces are possible by going into the `node_modules` directory and looking at `ask-sdk-model/index.d.ts`.

As of v1.17.0 those are:

```
/**
 * An object listing each interface that the device supports. For example, if supportedInterfaces includes AudioPlayer {}, then you know that the device supports streaming audio using the AudioPlayer interface.
 * @interface
 */
export interface SupportedInterfaces {
    'Alexa.Presentation.APL'?: interfaces.alexa.presentation.apl.AlexaPresentationAplInterface;
    'AudioPlayer'?: interfaces.audioplayer.AudioPlayerInterface;
    'Display'?: interfaces.display.DisplayInterface;
    'VideoApp'?: interfaces.videoapp.VideoAppInterface;
    'Geolocation'?: interfaces.geolocation.GeolocationInterface;
}
```